# How can I detect the element with the classname is parent/above all the other class names?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

1. I am given class names like `class-1`, `class-2` or `class-3`
2. There can be many classes (not necessarily 3) but I will be knowing all the class names.
3. I don't know the DOM structure.
4. And I just know that there is one class(the element with this class) is the parent of all.

**But how should I find which is that class which is the parent/above all other known classes ?** Is it `class-1`, `class-2` or `class-3` ?

I have HTML something like this

```
    <div>
      <div> Hey nice talking to you </div>
      <div> Hey how are you</div>
      <div><br/></div>
      <div class="class-1">
        <div>Hey, are you there?</div>
        <div class="class-2">
          <div>How was the day</div>
          <div class="class-3"><br/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is something that I tried

```
    _findClass_1(html) {
      return Array.from(html.querySelectorAll('.class-1'));
    }

    _findClass_2(html) {
      return Array.from(html.querySelectorAll('.class-2'));
    }

    _findClass_3(html) {
      return Array.from(html.querySelectorAll('.class-3'));
    }

    // Parser
    getNodes(html) {
      const parsers = [
        this._findClass_1,
        this._findClass_2,
        this._findClass_3,
      ];

      let quotedNodes = [];

      for (const parser of parsers) {
        quotedNodes.push(parser(html) || []);
      }

      // How can I detect here which one was the parent of all? 
      return quotedNodes;
    }
```

Can you help me?
No jQuery, please.

Comment: Is there one element for each? Do you need to know the order, or just who is the parent?

Comment: Are you looking to just get the first class of the highest-level parent? If the first `div` has a class, would you get that one?

Comment: not necessarily all the classes are present but at least one class is present if there is just one class is present that itself is the parent.

Comment: I am looking for the element of that parent class.

Comment: I don't need to know the order. Just the parent of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is loop over the array and select the element and than check to see if the other 2 elements exist in it. The parent would be the one with the most matches. This assumes there is only one element of each. If there is more than more logic would be needed. (And we would need test cases for all the possible outcomes)

```js
var classes = [".class-1", ".class-2", ".class-3"]

var result = classes.reduce((obj, key, i, arr) => {
  const cpy = arr.slice()
  cpy.splice(i,1)
  const count =
    document.querySelector(key)
      .querySelectorAll(cpy.join(","))
        .length
  if (count > obj.count) {
    return { key, count }
  }
  return obj
}, {key:'', count:-1})

console.log(result.key)
```

```html
    <div>
      <div> Hey nice talking to you </div>
      <div> Hey how are you</div>
      <div><br/></div>
      <div class="class-1">
        <div>Hey, are you there?</div>
        <div class="class-2">
          <div>How was the day</div>
          <div class="class-3"><br/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest of painful approach would be to traverse the DOM from the root node & stop as soon as any immediate child equals from one of many classes in the list.

```
const class_list = [];

recursion(element) {
  if (element === null) return false;

  // If element has one of the class from the list of class then return element.parentNode

  const children = element.children;
  children.forEach(child => recursion(element));

  return false;
}
```

start the process by calling

```
const parent_node = recursion(document.getElementById('body'));
if (parent_node) // this is the parent that has all the class element children
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a modern browser, you can use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to see if there are any ancestor elements which have one of the other classes. If not, then you've found the top-most element with a class. This assumes that there is only one element of each class in the DOM.

Basically, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) lets me go through the array and aggregate using a function. The function gets the current class and finds the element with that class. It then gets the array of classes (except the one we're testing) and finds if the current element has one of those as a parent. If not, we have the top-most element.

```js
const parent = ["class-1","class-2","class-3"].reduce((agg, cur, idx, arr) => {
  const sut = document.querySelector(`.${cur}`);
  const hasParent = arr.filter(e => e !== cur).some(clas => sut.closest(`.${clas}`) !== null);
  return hasParent ? agg : sut;
}, null);

console.log(parent.className);
```

```html
    <div>
      <div> Hey nice talking to you </div>
      <div> Hey how are you</div>
      <div><br/></div>
      <div class="class-1">
        <div>Hey, are you there?</div>
        <div class="class-2">
          <div>How was the day</div>
          <div class="class-3"><br/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the presence of (existence) the individual classes, look at the .innerHTML of the individual elements in each class array to see if the other found classes are found in there (making that a parent of the found one). Then keep track.  Now, does a subsequent found class have an element that contains the current parent?  Do the same thing: search the innerHTML on each element in it.  Good luck.

Comment: Why in the world would you look at the innerHTML for classes when you have the DOM. Would you use a string match?

Comment: That's what I was thinking (a regex or array of 'needles' depending on the actual class names). Your answer is basically the same (Only thing I can think of is loop over the array and select the element and than check to see if the other 2 elements exist in it.), but I like your `querySelectorAll(cpy.join(",")` though to find using selectors instead of text. Thx,